# Bake Simple Deform animation into mesh for Unity3D export?

Tags: animation, modifiers, unity

I'm trying to use a .blend file with a keyframe animation on the angle of a Simple Deform modifier in Unity3D. Unity3D however does not know how to handle modifiers and hence cannot play the animation.

How can I bake/save the animation to the .blend file so that Unity3D can play it?

Comment: Did you try to apply the modifier as a shape key and export the shape key into unity? The shape key animation won't export from what I gather, but you can re-animate it in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much ways to do that… Only one I can think of is applying enough 'keyframes' of your deform animation as shapekeys (you can copy modifier, apply as shapekey the copy, go five frames later, copy, apply as shapekey the copy, etc.), and then in Unity (or Blender), create an animation interpolating between those shapekeys. But this will be rather painful to set up I’m afraid.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of third party assets to do this for you, the MegaFiers asset for example has most of the modifiers/deformers found in Max, Maya etc so you could maybe recreate it with that, it also has support for Point Cache playback of industry standard cache files such as .pc2 .mdd and .mc files.

Comment: Yeah, I could, if only I had the money... can't afford it unfortunately. I'm bound to using free stuff like Blender and Unity Free. But thanks anyway for the advice.